# Learning While Loops. Can't figure out what I am missing in my code.

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

Write a function called indexToString. This function should:
1. Take an array as an argument
2. Create and return a new array of all passed array elements as strings
3. Each strings should be formatted like so: “[index] is [element at index]”
This is the error I am getting: returns an array of passed-in array elements as strings with element index specified
expected undefined to deeply equal [ '0 is 1', '1 is 2', '2 is 3' ]

Here is my code:

```
var indexToString = function(array){
  index = 0;
  elementAtIndex = 0;
  var i = 0;
  while(i < array.length){
    console.log(index + " is " + elementAtIndex);

    i++
  }
  return array[i];
};
```

Comment: `index` and `elementAtIndex` are never defined or changed to be anything but `0`.

Comment: Picking the above answer. your `index` is the `i`, and your `elementAtIndex` is `array[i]`, because you are accessing the element `i` from the array.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Two</strike> Three errors.

Firstly, the while loop will exit when `i` is no longer less than `array.length`; the first such number is `array.length`. This means, at the end of the loop, `array[i]` is `array[array.length]`, which is just outside the array, thus `undefined`.

Secondly, you are supposed to return an array of strings, as told by your test failure message; not print them to the console.

EDIT: Thirdly, what Spencer said. :) Use `i` instead of `index`, and `array[i]` instead of `elementAtIndex`.

You want to start with an empty array outside the loop, and push each string you construct into it; then return that array after the loop.

Or you can do it with "new" JavaScript:

```
var indexToString = array => array.map((e, i) => `${i} is ${e}`)
```

Comment: Using ES6 code is nice, although since the OP is quite new to JavaScript I don't think they would understand what's going on there.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Yes. It is an advanced topic, for sure - that's why it's in straight code. The "old way" is pretty much spelled out in the hints, I wanted OP to write it for themselves.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that's why you did that, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should reflect a bit more on your code, it is quite nonsense so far.

Let's decompose the question to identify what should be done:

> Write a function called **indexToString**. This function should:
>
> 1. Take an **array as an argument**
> 2. **Create and return a new array** of all passed array elements as **strings**
> 3. Each **strings** should be formatted like so: **“[index] is [element at index]”**

So:

- you create a function called **indexToString** which body contains the code, as you did.
- In the **initialization part** before your while, you should **create a new empty array** that is going to be filled, and declare an **integer** called **index** for example initialized at 0 that is going to be used to loop through the original array. (Tip: var new_array = []; to create, and use new_array.push(*elem*); to append an element)
- in your while, you should **push** at the end of your **new array** a string built as follow: "["+index+"] is ["+array[index]+"]" AND you should increment your index. You loop `while(index < array.length)`.

At the end, you can return the **new array** !

Good luck with learning programming!

Comment: Yes, It is all still very new to me. I get confused and lost pretty easily. Thank you for the tips though. You broke down perfectly. Really helped me figure it out!!

Answer (score 0):

If the arraylenth is 10, the function will return array[10].This is an array-bound.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the last loop, the `i` becomes equal to `array.length`, so `array[i]` is undefined after this. But probably this is not what you wanted. you want to return the full array.

```js
var indexToString = function(array){
  var new_array = [];
  var i = 0;
  while(i < array.length){
    new_array[i] = i + " is " + array[i];
    i++;
  }
  return new_array;
};

console.log(indexToString([1,2,3]));
```